# How to schedule processes in FCFS algorithm using arrival time?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling

Here is my definition of FCFS (First Come First Serve - CPU Scheduling algorithm):

```
Process     CPU Burst        Arrival Time
p1          4                0
p2          5                1
p3          6                2
p4          5                1
p5          4                0
```

And the sequence of this example is as below
[image]

So my question is that in second turn why it doesn't take p5 instead of p4 as its arrival time is also 0?

Comment: From which book is this question and solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FCFS` is implemented through [**Queue**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/dsa_queue.htm) data structure. So it all depends on the position of processes in the `FCFS queue`, based on which `short term scheduler` will select process for execution.

Since arrival time of `p5` is less than `p4`, it will definitely be ahead of p4 in the `queue` and therefore, it must be executed first. The **Gantt Chart** you have drawn is **wrong**.

One of the correct sequence could be:

```
p1 , p5 , p2 , p4 , p3
```

Comment: It is not his solution I guess.

Comment: yes it was not my solution, it was an answer shown in assignment which didn't match my solution as i did the same as @Sumeet Singh.